# How I can completely remove everything generated by gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I installed the Redactor gem, but after some time I decided that this gem doesn't suit my needs. I removed it from Gemfile, and also removed all of the gem's files (I suppose) in all app folders.

When I try to deploy app, the server fails to start with this error:

```
uninitialized constant Redactor Rails
```

It points to the folder which I actually removed (in models). Each time it is created while I'm pushing the app to the server (with git).

How can I completely remove ALL the files that the gem generated?

Comment: Since you're using git, can't you just revert the commit that installed the gem in the first place?

Comment: @Ajedi32, I don't want to loose progress I made while gem was installed in other things

Comment: is there something in config/initializers?

Comment: You can revert a specific commit using `git revert` without loosing other progress. (Given that you installed gem in a separate commit.)

Comment: Just removing it from the Gemfile isn't enough. You'll need to bundle again to remove it from Gemfile.lock. I'm a fan of rolling forward instead of reverting, so I'd look at the commit and see what files it changed or spawned into your application, and just undo and remove that way. Something, somewhere in your app is referencing "Redactor".

Answer (score 1):

You sure did

```
gem uninstall redactor-rails
```

Remove in your application.js

```
//= require redactor-rails
```

also in your application.css

```
*= require redactor-rails
```

The gem also generated in

```
app/uploaders/redactor_rails_document_uploader.rb

app/models/redactor_rails/document.rb
```

Comment: I did it all for sure. Even more, deleted all generated by redactor in schema.rb But each time I deployed, heroku generated all this files again! Can't say why. Finally git reset was the only option.